# Specify action in JSF 2.0 composite

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I want to create a composite component that outputs a `<button>` tag. This tag will wrap other content. I know that one option would be to write my own component and renderer. However, I would prefer to do it as a composite. The only problem I can foresee is specifying an action when my `<button>` tag is clicked.

Does anyone know if it's possible to specify an action on a custom composite?

Answer (score 1):

When defining composite components, you can specify that your component is action source:

```
<cc:interface>
  <!-- ... -->
  <cc:actionSource name="myButton" targets="myButton"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
  <!-- ... -->
  <h:commandButton id="myButton" value="My Button"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</cc:implementation>
```

With this, you made your composite component action source, and you can define action listeners in your component:

```
<my:customComponent id="component">
  <f:actionListener for="myButton" binding="#{myBean.action}"/>
</my:customComponent>
```